# Is it possible to call a function inside a data.table operation?

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I'd like to run more fastly a simulation by group from nls model.
df is a data frame

Some data (df):

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 x   x
9   aa  bb  4   0.073
9   aa  bb  40  0.033
9   aa  bb  100 0.024
9   aa  bb  400 0.017
7   bb  bb  4   0.142
7   bb  bb  40  0.072
7   bb  bb  100 0.059
7   bb  bb  400 0.037
9   bb  bb  4   0.349
9   bb  bb  40  0.235
9   bb  bb  100 0.192
9   bb  bb  400 0.135
```

This works with plyr:

```
library(plyr)

form <- formula(y ~ m * x^(-n))
s <- list(m=1, n=0.5)
x.range <- seq(1, 1000, length.out=30000)

sim.df <- ddply(df, 
               c("ID1","ID2","ID3"), 
               function(a) {
                 m1 <- nls(form, data=a, start=s)
                 y.pred <- predict(m1, newdata=data.frame(x=x.range))
                 data.frame(x=x.range, y=y.pred)
               })
```

Is there a way to do something similar with data.table? I tried the following but the syntax might be too inspired from plyr...

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.frame(df)

sim.dt <- dt[,
              function(a) {
                m1 <- nls(form, data=a, start=s)
                y.pred <- predict(m1, newdata=data.frame(x=x.range))
                data.frame(x=x.range, y=y.pred)
              },
              by=list(ID1,ID2,ID3)
              ]
```

I get this ERROR: *j evaluates to type 'closure'. Must evaluate to atomic vector or list*

Comment: I think it might work, if you definded the function outside of the data.table call and then used `dt[, fun(.SD), by=list(ID1,ID2,ID3)]`. And of course you need to use `setDT(dt)` to actually make it a data.table. Right now it's a data.frame.

Comment: But the bottleneck for speed is `nls`. data.table can't help with this.

Comment: See also [data.table: anonymous function in j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898162/data-table-anonymous-function-in-j)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about what you're doing. In `data.table`, the second argument is an expression (unlike `ddply`'s 3rd argument, which is a function) - and right now you just gave it an anonymous function.

No reproducible data in OP to test, but my guess is you simply want:

```
dt[, {
       m1 <- nls(form, data=.SD, start=s)
       y.pred <- predict(m1, newdata=data.frame(x=x.range))
       list(x=x.range, y=y.pred)
     },
   by=list(ID1,ID2,ID3)]
```

Comment: I think this needs `data = .SD`.