# data.table: anonymous function in j

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to have an anonymous function return multiple columns in the `j` argument of a `data.table`. Here's an example:

```
## sample data
tmpdt <- data.table(a = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)),
                    b = c(rep("f", 3), rep("r", 7)),
                    c = 1:10,
                    d = 21:30)
tmpdt[c %in% c(2,4), c := NA]

## this works fine
tmpdt[ , list(testout =
                (function(x) {
                    model <- lm(c ~ d, x)
                    residuals(model)
                })(.SD)),
      by = a]

## but I want to return a data.frame from the
## anonymous function

tmpdt[ , list(testout =
                (function(x) {
                    model <- lm(c ~ d, x)
                    tmpresid <- residuals(model)
                    tmpvalue <- x$b[as.numeric(names(tmpresid))]
                    data.frame(tmpvalue, tmpresid)
                })(.SD)),
      by = a]
```

The second version doesn't work because the function returns a `data.frame` instead of just a vector. Is there any way to make this work without writing the function call outside of the data.table `j` argument?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need an anonymous functions - you can have whatever expression you want wrapped in `{ }` (anonymous *body*) in `j`.

```
tmpdt[, {
          model <- lm(c ~ d, .SD)
          tmpresid <- residuals(model)
          tmpvalue <- b[as.numeric(names(tmpresid))]
          list(tmpvalue, tmpresid) # every element of the list becomes a column in result
        }
      , by = a]
```

---

Some documentation on the use of anonymous body `{ }` in `j`:

1. Comment in **Examples** in `?data.table`:

> anonymous lambda in `j`: `j` accepts any valid expression. TO REMEMBER: every element of the `list` becomes a column in result.

2. [`data.table` FAQ 2.8 What are the scoping rules for `j` expressions?](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#what-are-the-scoping-rules-for-j-expressions)

> No anonymous *function* is passed to `j`. Instead, an anonymous *body* [`{ }`] is passed to `j` [...] Some programming languages call this a *lambda*.

3. Blog post by Andrew Brooks on the use of `{ }` in `j`: [Suppressing intermediate output with {}](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#suppressing-intermediate-output-with-)

Comment: Even more elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized the issue right after I did it. No need to have a list:

```
tmpdt[,(function(x) {
                    model <- lm(c~d,x)
                    tmpresid <- residuals(model)
                    tmpvalue <- x$b[as.numeric(names(tmpresid))]
                    data.frame(tmpvalue,tmpresid)
                })(.SD)),
      by=a]
```