# Data.table using computed field in consecutive computation

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently using the data.table package in R to produce additional columns. I intend to use any computed values in successive/ consecutive step.

For example, I have data like this

```
Data <- data.table(a = 1, b = 2)
```

I want to calculate:

Column "c" = column "a" (given) + column "b" (given)

Column "d" = column "c" * 0.40 (some other function here)

I used the following code:

```
Data[ ,`:=`((c = a + b), (d = c * 0.40))]
```

I receive an error for following this approach stating

> Column "c" does not exist.

I intend performing these operations multiple times and was intending for these code not to be split.

Is there a way to perform this operation without splitting the code into multiple sections and also ensuring the output is written to the same data.table?
Thanks

Comment: I think this has been answered before, but can't find it right now. Some alternatives: (1a) LHS `:=` RHS form: `Data[ , c("c", "d") := .(c <- a + b, c * 2)]`; (1b) Slightly more verbose, using `{ }`: `Data[ , c("c", "d") := {c <- a + b; .(c , c * 2)}]`: (2) Functional form: ``Data[ , `:=`(c = c <- a + b, d = c * 2)]``. Relevant: [data.table: anonymous function in j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898162/data-table-anonymous-function-in-j).

Comment: The topic is also discussed in [this open issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/659)

Comment: What is the reason, why *chaining* `Data[, c := a + b][, d := c * 0.40]` cannot be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some alternatives:

1. LHS `:=` RHS form

(a)  `Data[ , c("c", "d") := .(c <- a + b, c * 2)]`

(b) Slightly more verbose, using `{ }`

```
Data[ , c("c", "d") := {
  c <- a + b
  .(c , c * 2)}]
```

(2) Functional form

```
Data[ , `:=`(c = c <- a + b, d = c * 2)]
```

---

See also:

[data.table: anonymous function in j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898162/data-table-anonymous-function-in-j)

The topic is also discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/659)