# R Filling the leading and lagging values in data.table if some condition occurs

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table as follows -

```
NA20 <- rep(NA, 20)
dt <-  data.table(
  group = c(rep("A", 20), rep("B", 20), "C", "D", rep("E", 20)), 
  val = c(replace(NA20, 11, 2), replace(NA20, 6, 2), 2, NA, replace(NA20, c(5, 15), 2)))

> dt
    group val
 1:     A  NA
 2:     A  NA
 3:     A  NA
 4:     A  NA
 5:     A  NA
 6:     A  NA
 7:     A  NA
 8:     A  NA
 9:     A  NA
10:     A  NA
11:     A   2
12:     A  NA
13:     A  NA
14:     A  NA
15:     A  NA
16:     A  NA
17:     A  NA
18:     A  NA
19:     A  NA
20:     A  NA
21:     B  NA
22:     B  NA
23:     B  NA
24:     B  NA
25:     B  NA
26:     B   2
27:     B  NA
28:     B  NA
29:     B  NA
30:     B  NA
31:     B  NA
32:     B  NA
33:     B  NA
34:     B  NA
35:     B  NA
36:     B  NA
37:     B  NA
38:     B  NA
39:     B  NA
40:     B  NA
41:     C   2
42:     D  NA
43:     E  NA
44:     E  NA
45:     E  NA
46:     E  NA
47:     E   2
48:     E  NA
49:     E  NA
50:     E  NA
51:     E  NA
52:     E  NA
53:     E  NA
54:     E  NA
55:     E  NA
56:     E  NA
57:     E   2
58:     E  NA
59:     E  NA
60:     E  NA
61:     E  NA
62:     E  NA
```

In the `val` column, if the value is 2, I want to fill the previous 7 values with -1 and next 7 values with 1. This operation should be done by the group.

The output looks like following -

```
    group val new
 1:     A  NA  NA
 2:     A  NA  NA
 3:     A  NA  NA
 4:     A  NA  -1
 5:     A  NA  -1
 6:     A  NA  -1
 7:     A  NA  -1
 8:     A  NA  -1
 9:     A  NA  -1
10:     A  NA  -1
11:     A   2   2
12:     A  NA   1
13:     A  NA   1
14:     A  NA   1
15:     A  NA   1
16:     A  NA   1
17:     A  NA   1
18:     A  NA   1
19:     A  NA  NA
20:     A  NA  NA
21:     B  NA  -1
22:     B  NA  -1
23:     B  NA  -1
24:     B  NA  -1
25:     B  NA  -1
26:     B   2   2
27:     B  NA   1
28:     B  NA   1
29:     B  NA   1
30:     B  NA   1
31:     B  NA   1
32:     B  NA   1
33:     B  NA   1
34:     B  NA  NA
35:     B  NA  NA
36:     B  NA  NA
37:     B  NA  NA
38:     B  NA  NA
39:     B  NA  NA
40:     B  NA  NA
41:     C   2   2
42:     D  NA  NA
43:     E  NA  -1
44:     E  NA  -1
45:     E  NA  -1
46:     E  NA  -1
47:     E   2   2
48:     E  NA   1
49:     E  NA   1
50:     E  NA  -1
51:     E  NA  -1
52:     E  NA  -1
53:     E  NA  -1
54:     E  NA  -1
55:     E  NA  -1
56:     E  NA  -1
57:     E   2   2
58:     E  NA   1
59:     E  NA   1
60:     E  NA   1
61:     E  NA   1
62:     E  NA   1
```

I came around a few corner cases and due to that some of the solutions below stopped working. I will appreciate it if solutions can be updated to cover these scenarios. I have updated the data above. Listed below are scenarios.

Only Uwe's and pseudospin's solutions are 100% correct and cover all following corner cases -

1. All values in a group are NA
2. There is only one value `2` in a group
3. There are multiple `2's` and when they will override, precedence is to be given to `1` instead of `-1`. (not must, but good to have scenario)

Thanks

Comment: What if the blocks of 7 values overlap?

Comment: They will never overlap. All 2's are at safe distance.

Comment: Is there only one `2` per group as your sample data suggest? Or is it possible to have multiple occurrences of `2` in each group (without overlap)?

Comment: Re: _There are multiple occurrences of 2 in each group_, please provide _all_ relevant conditions and relevant data in your question.

Comment: For next time: please, please think _carefully_ on your question _before_ posting, to avoid making the question a moving target, i.e. to avoid that people spend their time on answers which will become invalidated when the question is evolving.

Comment: Point taken. Apologies to all whose solutions become invalidated due to the addition of corner cases. Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is solution which uses `data.table`'s `fcase()` and `inrange()` functions. It handles also multiple occurrences of `2` in a group as well as the other edge cases. For demonstration, I have added a group `E` to the sample dataset:

```
NA20 <- rep(NA, 20)
dt1 <-  data.table(
  group = c(rep("A", 20), rep("B", 20), "C", "D", rep("E", 20)), 
  val = c(replace(NA20, 11, 2), replace(NA20, 6, 2), 2, NA, replace(NA20, c(5, 15), 2)))

dt1[, new := {
  rn <- 1:.N
  i2 <- which(val == 2)
  fcase(
    rn %inrange% .(i2 - 7, i2 - 1), -1,
    rn %inrange% .(i2 + 1, i2 + 7), 1,
    rn %in% i2, val
  )
}, by = group][]
```

> ```
>     group val new
>  1:     A  NA  NA
>  2:     A  NA  NA
>  3:     A  NA  NA
>  4:     A  NA  -1
>  5:     A  NA  -1
>  6:     A  NA  -1
>  7:     A  NA  -1
>  8:     A  NA  -1
>  9:     A  NA  -1
> 10:     A  NA  -1
> 11:     A   2   2
> 12:     A  NA   1
> 13:     A  NA   1
> 14:     A  NA   1
> 15:     A  NA   1
> 16:     A  NA   1
> 17:     A  NA   1
> 18:     A  NA   1
> 19:     A  NA  NA
> 20:     A  NA  NA
> 21:     B  NA  -1
> 22:     B  NA  -1
> 23:     B  NA  -1
> 24:     B  NA  -1
> 25:     B  NA  -1
> 26:     B   2   2
> 27:     B  NA   1
> 28:     B  NA   1
> 29:     B  NA   1
> 30:     B  NA   1
> 31:     B  NA   1
> 32:     B  NA   1
> 33:     B  NA   1
> 34:     B  NA  NA
> 35:     B  NA  NA
> 36:     B  NA  NA
> 37:     B  NA  NA
> 38:     B  NA  NA
> 39:     B  NA  NA
> 40:     B  NA  NA
> 41:     C   2   2
> 42:     D  NA  NA
> 43:     E  NA  -1
> 44:     E  NA  -1
> 45:     E  NA  -1
> 46:     E  NA  -1
> 47:     E   2   2
> 48:     E  NA   1
> 49:     E  NA   1
> 50:     E  NA  -1
> 51:     E  NA  -1
> 52:     E  NA  -1
> 53:     E  NA  -1
> 54:     E  NA  -1
> 55:     E  NA  -1
> 56:     E  NA  -1
> 57:     E   2   2
> 58:     E  NA   1
> 59:     E  NA   1
> 60:     E  NA   1
> 61:     E  NA   1
> 62:     E  NA   1
>     group val new
> ```

In group `E` there are two occurrences of `2`. Out of curosity, I have arbitrarily chosen to overlap the areas. As can be seen from the result, the first condition in the call to `fcase()` "wins", i.e., there are seven contiguous `-1` *before* the second occurrence of `2`. This can be verified by interchanging the first and second condition in the call to `fcase()`. Then, we would get seven contiguous `1` *after* the first occurrence of `2`.

Also note that `data.table::fcase()` and `dplyr::case_when()` (used in [AnilGoyal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66192824/3817004)) differ in how parameters are interpreted.

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191616/r-fill-the-leading-and-lagging-values-in-data-table-if-condition-occurs/66194343#comment117027787_66194343) asked for an explanation of the statements inside the `{}` clause.
In `data.table` syntax `x[i, j, by]`, `i` and `j` can be expressions. So, `rn` and `i2` are created as temporary variables inside each `group` in order to save typing and repeated evaluation of the same expressions.

- `rn <- 1:.N` is a vector of row numbers within each group where `.N` is a special symbol containing the number of rows in the group. `1:.N` is equivalent to `dplyr::row_number()`.
- `i2 <- which(val == 2)` is a vector of indices (within the group) where the condition `val == 2` is met.

The whole `{}` expression is a more readable version of

```
fcase(
  1:.N %inrange% .(which(val == 2) - 7, which(val == 2) - 1), -1,
  1:.N %inrange% .(which(val == 2) + 1, which(val == 2) + 7), 1,
  1:.N %in% which(val == 2), val
)
```

#### Caveat

The column `val` of OP's sample dataset is of type *double* but the OP is asking to test for *equality*. Due to the finite representation of numbers testing equality of doubles may lead to unexpected results (not in this use case, obviously). Therefore, I suggest to use either type *integer* where appropriate or to consider  *numerical tolerances* in *if* clauses involving doubles.

BTW: `data.table` is particular picky on data types, for good reason.

Comment: Good one. Please explain what three statements inside {} do in dt syntax?

Comment: Thanks for handling multiple occurrences of 2 in a group. Point taken, I will keep ```val``` type as integer.

Comment: @AnilGoyal, I have added an additional explanation to my answer. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Actually I am not aware that we can write multiple statements inside {}.

Comment: @AnilGoyal See also this nice answer: [data.table: anonymous function in j](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25898349/1851712)

Answer (score 3):

This'll do it, but it's pretty ugly. Must be a nicer way.

```
dt[, val :={
  w <- which(val == 2)
  val[unlist(sapply(w, function(x) max(1, x-7):(x-1)))] <- -1
  val[unlist(sapply(w, function(x) (x+1):min(.N, x+7)))] <- 1
  val
}, group]
```

---

Here's my updated version - covers all the edge cases that have been mentioned, and also ensures you don't override a 2 if two 2s are closer than 7 apart

```
dt[, val := {
  w <- which(val == 2)
  iplus <- outer(w, 1:7, '+') # outer is faster than sapply for big vectors
  iminus <- iplus-8
  iminus <- setdiff(setdiff(iminus[iminus >= 1], iplus), w)
  iplus <- setdiff(iplus[iplus <= .N], w)
  val[iplus] <- 1
  val[iminus] <- -1
  val
}, group]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for all cases except where ```2``` is the last value in a group. Seems like ```function(x) (x+1):min(.N, x+7)))``` is failing due to ```x+1```

Comment: (1) You said *"All 2's are at safe distance"*, which suggests to me that 2s are never close to boundaries as well as are distant from each other. (2) To be fair, if you have that as a likelihood, you really should state it and/or include it in your sample data.

Comment: (1) With safe distance, I meant that two 2's won't come close to each other in a group to cause overlapping issues. (2) Sure, I have updated the sample data to include this corner case.

Comment: Thanks @pseudospin for covering the corner cases!

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while, but I was finally able to beat pseudospin's speedy answer. (I'm not fond of `{` in `data.table` expressions, but it works. For readability, I'd likely but the bracketed code within a function .. since really it's just looking at a vector at a time, so it doesn't matter much.)

```r
dt[, val2 := {
  o <- outer(seq_len(.N), which(val %in% 2), `-`)
  o[abs(o) > 7] <- NA
  o <- do.call(pmin, c(asplit(o, 2), list(na.rm = TRUE)))
  replace(sign(o), o == 0, 2)
}, by = .(group) ]
```

Benchmarks:

```r
bench::mark(
  pseudospin = dt[, val2 :={
    w <- which(val == 2)
    val[unlist(sapply(w, function(x) max(1, x-7):(x-1)))] <- -1
    val[unlist(sapply(w, function(x) (x+1):min(.N, x+7)))] <- 1
    val
  }, group],
  r2evans = dt[, val2 := {
    o <- outer(seq_len(.N), which(val %in% 2), `-`)
    o[abs(o) > 7] <- NA
    o <- do.call(pmin, c(asplit(o, 2), list(na.rm = TRUE)))
    replace(sign(o), o == 0, 2)
  }, by = .(group) ]
)
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression    min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result        memory      time     gc       
#   <bch:expr> <bch:> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>        <list>      <list>   <list>   
# 1 pseudospin  594us   644us     1431.    34.8KB     2.06   695     1      486ms <data.table[~ <Rprofmem[~ <bch:tm~ <tibble ~
# 2 r2evans     568us   610us     1511.    35.1KB     2.06   735     1      486ms <data.table[~ <Rprofmem[~ <bch:tm~ <tibble ~
```

... though I wouldn't call that a landslide. And to be honest, run it another time or two and pseudospin's is faster. Either way, they both work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `dplyr` solution for reference

```
dt %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(val = case_when(row_number() >= row_number()[val %in% 2] -7 & row_number() < row_number()[val %in% 2] ~ -1,
                         row_number() <= row_number()[val %in% 2] +7 & row_number() > row_number()[val %in% 2] ~ 1,
                         TRUE ~ val))

# A tibble: 40 x 2
# Groups:   group [2]
   group   val
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 A        NA
 2 A        NA
 3 A        NA
 4 A        -1
 5 A        -1
 6 A        -1
 7 A        -1
 8 A        -1
 9 A        -1
10 A        -1
# ... with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Why `%>% data.frame()`?

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I thought data.table won't run without converting it to 'data.frame`.  Editing it now.  Thanks again @r2evans

Comment: That's one of the powers of both `tbl_df` and `data.table`: they both inherit from `data.frame`.